# How to use crossunder() method to detect where price is interacting with Fibonacci levels in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v4

I'm fairly new at coding pinescript and am trying to code a custom alert where if price crosses under a fibonacci golden level (0.382, 0.50, or 0.618) and bar state is confirmed, it will return true and trigger an alert.

FYI, I'm analyzing and building upon TradingView's built-in Auto Fib Retracement Indicator script to use as an alert. I'm having difficulty trying to retrieve the fibonacci values to compare. I notice when using auto fib retracement tool, it plots the fibonacci level (in decimal format) along with the price and I was wondering how do I retrieve it to compare where price has hit the levels within it if that's the correct way to go about it?

**Code Snippet (my added alert code from the bult-in indicator):**

```
crossFibGoldenLvls = low < value_0_382 and barstate.isconfirmed // if the 0.382 level price is greater than the current bar low AND bar state is confirmed; thus returns the bar’s final price
// if price cross down thru any of these golden levels (0.382, 0.50, 0.618) AND then 2 green consecutive candles close higher than previous bar close, return true
if crossFibGoldenLvls
    alert("Price has crossed a fib golden level.", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    //alert("Price has crossed a fib golden level:" + tostring(processLevel(show_1, value_1, color_1)), alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
// else if price cross down thru any of these levels (0.786, 1), return false
// …

//plot(series=processLevel(show_0_382, value_0_382, color_0_382), title="fib level 0.382")
//plot(series=processLevel(value_0_382), title="fib level 0.382")
plotchar(show_0_382, title="show_0_382")
plotchar(value_0_382, title="value_0_382")
//plotchar(value, title="value")
//plotchar(m, title="m")
//plotchar(r, title="r")
plotchar(diff, title="diff")
plotchar(startPrice, title="startPrice")
plotchar(endPrice, title="endPrice")
//plotchar(price, title="price")
//plotchar(crossFibGoldenLvls, title="crossFibGoldenLvls")
```

Tradingview’s auto fib retracement tool can be found [here](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000585089-auto-fib-retracement/) along with its full source code. The code snippet above is what I added to it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value_0_382` holds the fibonacci level actually (0.382). What you are looking for is calculated within the `processLevel()` function and named `r`.

You can easily check that modifying the code such that `processLevel()` returns the value of `r` and plot the returned value.

```
processLevel(show, value, colorL) =>
    float m = value
    r = startPrice + diff * m
    if show
        _draw_line(r, colorL)
        _draw_label(r, _label_txt(m, r), colorL)
        if _crossing_level(close, r)
            alert("Autofib: " + syminfo.ticker + " crossing level " + tostring(value))
    r

pl = processLevel(show_0_382, value_0_382, color_0_382)
plot(pl)
```

[image]

Then use this return value in your condition:

```
crossFibGoldenLvls = low < pl and barstate.isconfirmed
```

Comment: I tried the code above but I get this error: `Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 210: Void expression cannot be assigned to a variable` on this line of code: `pl = processLevel(show_0_382, value_0_382, color_0_382)`. Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: Did you modify the function?

Comment: No, only the variable name to match its corresponding level, in this case 0.382 and I think I have to create a var for each level passed in. Here's my full code here, which you copy and paste into pinescript to see the error: https://pastebin.com/HyHKuMEL

Comment: Well, you need to modify it because as it is in the original script, it is a `void` function, hence you get the error. Please see my edit. I gave you the complete function description that you need to have.